# Access to user's input dictionary

Tags: android, mobile-development

Is it possible for an Android application to figure out what words phone's owner types most frequently on the phone? I assume this might not be the case due to privacy concerns, but decided to ask just in case.

The idea was for an app to "adapt" to user based on the analyzation of most used keywords.

Thank you in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible unless the android device is rooted, as there are definitely security concerns with allowing an application to have a global key-input hook.

I believe, however, that the operating system itself already does this to an extent. I certainly do not have any definitive evidence, but I've come to notice that the auto-suggestion feature implemented in the standard keyboard suggests very peculiar things that only I would say.